# How can I allow a role of users to access a content type in Drupal6?

Tags: drupal

I want to allow only one type of user to access a certain content type. It's simple and I've done it before, but today I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this requires an access control module like [Node Access.](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) Using a module like that, you can completely hide certain kinds of content from users who aren't allowed to view them.

Comment: Thanks, but I think there is a simpler way. I did it before without node access. I am basically trying to hide a page from some users

Comment: Sorry, but Eaton is correct - the proper way to restrict users' access to content is to use roles and access control. To map access control to particular content types, use the "Taxonomy Access Control Lite" module.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "read" access, you'll indeed need some form of access control module, as Eaton suggested. [OG](http://drupal.org/project/og), for instance, is one access control module although quite often people don't think of it that way due to its other features.

If you mean edit/delete access, OTOH, you have these by node type vs role at `admin/user/permissions`.

And, of course, if you only want to hide nodes from non-admins, you can just unpublish them: only admins will see them.